# HTML submit text value with line breaks

Tags: html, mailto

I am making a quiz with checkbox'es and the answers get sent by e-mail.
but when the answers get posted to the e-mail body there are no line breaks, \n, `&#10`;, `&#38;#10`.... do not work, please advise

```
<form method=post action=mailto:derp@derp.com>
<ol>
Name:<thisUserName><p>
<li>
    How do you spell cat?<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='A'>
    KAT<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='B'>
    Kit-Kat<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='C'>
    Cat<br>
<li>
    <IMG SRC=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Schrodingers_cat.svg height="400" width="400">.   <br>
    According to Schrödinger is the cat alive or dead?<p>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='A'>
    Dead<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='B'>
    Alive<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='C'>
    Both<br>
<li>
    What do you know about cats?<p>
Answer:<input type=textarea name=Answer3 rows="5" cols="20" wrap="physical"  ><br>
<center><input type='submit' value='Submit answers by e-mail'  onClick='alert("Quiz answers are being sent by e-mail.")'></center></ol>
</form>
```

the e-mail body looks like `Q1=A&Q2=A&Answer3=meow` 
and I want it to look like

```
Q1=A
Q2=A
Answer3=meow
```

Comment: This should be done by PHP, not HTML.

Comment: @user3636021 note: next time when post a question remove private data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution worked

```
<form method="post"  enctype="text/plain" action="mailto:johncitizen@example.com?subject=my%20test%20form">
<ol>
Name:<thisUserName><p>
<li>
    How do you spell cat?<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='A'>
    KAT<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='B'>
    Kit-Kat<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q1' value ='C'>
    Cat<br>
<li>
    <IMG SRC=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Schrodingers_cat.svg height="400" width="400">.   <br>
    According to Schrödinger is the cat alive or dead?<p>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='A'>
    Dead<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='B'>
    Alive<br>
    <input type ='checkbox' name = 'Q2' value ='C'>
    Both<br>
<li>
    What do you know about cats?<p>
Answer:<input type=textarea name=Answer3 rows="5" cols="20" wrap="physical"  ><br>
<center><input type='submit' value='Submit answers by e-mail'  onClick='alert("Quiz answers are being sent by e-mail.")'></center></ol>
</form>
```